# Most ideal way to call firebase getIdToken

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

i am implementing user authentication with the help of firebase in my React project. So, I am confused over something.

I am verifying the user from firebase and then getting a token on frontend which is sent to backend via headers and verfied there once.

I read the docs and came to know that  firebase token gets expired after 1 hr by default so we have to use "getIdToken" like

```
 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(async user => {
      if (user) {
        console.log(user, 'user123 inside firebaseAuth')
        const token = await user.getIdToken()

        Cookies.set('my_token', token, { domain: domain })
      }
    })
```

but how do i manage this function , do i have to call it everytime the component updates or everytime before hitting api or first time the component renders ?

The thing is i do not want this token to get expire until the user logs out himself / herself even if he is in a different component and sitting ideal for too long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the Firebase ID Token every time you are making an API call to your server:

```js
async function callAPI() {
  const user = firebase.auth().currentUser
  if (user) {
    const token = await user.getIdToken()
    const res = await fetch("url", {
      headers: {authorization: `Bearer ${token}`}
    })
  } else {
    console.log("No user is logged in")
  }
}
```

You could get the ID token once when the component mounts but then you'll have to deal with [onIdTokenChanged](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onidtokenchanged) to keep it updated in your state. Using the method above you'll get a valid token always.

Comment: so the onIdTokenChanged can be called on didmount and will always run when token refreshes ?

Comment: @Ratnabhkumarrai I'm not familiar with React but ideally you want to make sure that this `idTokenChanged` runs only once when the page loads.

Comment: ahh i see , okay

Comment: @Ratnabhkumarrai though I don't see any cons in getting the ID Token whenever you need it as mentioned in my callAPI function above